# String array sorting with special character

Tags: android, arrays, string, sorting

My String array is

```
1-2, 2-5, 5-6, 8-10, 3-5,
```

I need:

```
1-2, 2-5, 3-5, 5-6, 8-10
```

Comment: You need to write your own sort

Comment: what language do you use? java?

Comment: i use Android/Java

Comment: Some pre-existing "natural sort" algorithm might work (out of the box or as a basis), if you don't want to start from scratch.

Comment: Finally i got Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50871118/5069323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all of all you need to replace your Array list **"01-02, 02-05, 05-06, 08-10, 03-05"** Instead of "1-2, 2-5, 5-6, 8-10, 3-5"

After Replacing You can use Collection class

```
Collections.sort(headerArr, new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
                }
            });
```

Finally you got output like this

> 01-02, 02-05, 03-05, 05-06, 08-10

***Second Example of Above code***

==> Input

```
01-05, 08-09, 05-08, Morning, 11-11, 11-15, 11-13, 11-12, 80-90, Evening, 51-62, 10-11
```

==> Output

> 01-05, 05-08, 08-09, 10-11, 11-11, 11-12, 11-13, 11-15, 51-62, 80-90, Evening, Morning